# How to print message from another file function from index.js

Tags: discord.js

I am making discord bot

I want to call **testing.js** from **index.js** to send message and return variables.

**index.js**

```
import { Client, Embed, GatewayIntentBits, GuildMember, REST, Routes } from 'discord.js';
import testPing from './commands/testing.js';

testPing('ABC FGH');
```

**testing.js** (directory: commands)

```
function testPing(name){

   message.channel.send("Sentence "+name );

 }

export default (testPing);
```

It said : *ReferenceError: message is not defined*

What I should change with the message?

Thank You

```
Sentence test ABC FGH
```

Answer (score 1):

### The issue is exactly what you would expect it to be

`message` is not defined. You are trying to perform a function on a class **that doesn't exist**.

You first need to **handle an event** (in this case `messageCreate` event) in order to access the parameter it passes to you.

I highly suggest you read the **discord.js documentation**, there you will find out how to do that, [more specifically this page.](https://discordjs.guide/creating-your-bot/event-handling.html#individual-event-files)

---

If however, you want to send a message to some specific **static channel** you can do this:

```js
client.on("ready", async () => {
    ( client.channels.cache.get('CHANNEL ID') as TextChannel ).send('INSERT A STRING HERE!')
})
```

*P.S. Don't forget to login with your bots token!*